# Osx 'which' command working weird

Tags: python, macos, macports

To handle different versions of Python issue, I have installed a python27 using macport, later py27-pip, and execute the

```
sudo port install python27
sudo port install py27-pip
sudo port select --set pip pip27
sudo port select --set python python27
```

Later I was trying to use pip to install some packages. pip was still referring to Mac python instead of port python. I thought 'which' command should point to the correct pip version. But the results were

```
$which pip
/opt/local/bin/pip
$pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$/opt/local/bin/pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Can anyone help to point out why 'which' not working here?Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run `hash -r`, then `pip --version` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`which` is working just fine. But `which` doesn't reflect your shell lookup cache.

Whenever you run a command without a path in bash for the first time, bash caches the result of the `which` call. Subsequent use of that command doesn't then have to find the command in your `PATH` again.

You probably have run `pip` before you ran `sudo port select --set pip pip27`, and bash still has the old path cached.

Run `hash -d pip` to clear just that entry from the cache, or run `hash -r` to clear the cache entirely.

Comment: Thanks, Exactly, it's because of cache.